# Ignoring specific require()s in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

I have a library interoperable with NodeJS and the Browser and both are being run through Webpack to produce the final bundle. The issue I'm running into is Webpack will rewrite all `require()` statements to `__webpack_require__()` and try to bundle the library, which doesn't work for things like `fs` and `worker_threads`. How do I make it ignore certain `require()`s and related mechanisms (`require.resolve()`, `import`, etc) given a specific input string?

I've read that I can use the `webpack.IgnorePlugin` but I'd rather not have the user have to add a special rule in their build for my library. I also couldn't get this to work myself, it still rewrote the `require()`s. I've also read I can do `eval('require("fs")')` but this seems hacky, but I'm willing to do this if it's really the best way.

Example:

```
//example.js
if(typeof window !== "undefined") {
    //Browser
    var myWorker = new Worker();
}
else {
    //NodeJS
    var Worker = require("worker_threads"); //I want Webpack to keep this line as-is
    var myWorker = new Worker();
}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple working example of what you want?

Comment: @Adam Added example

Comment: Best way seemed to be `var _require = eval('require');` and then use that everywhere in the file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been researching this problem over the past few days and couldn't find a better option than what you suggest. I may create a package you can use specifically for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To keep a `require` call as-is in your code after bundling with Webpack, simply replace `require` with `__non_webpack_require__`. So your example will look like this:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    var myWorker = new Worker();
}
else {
    var Worker = __non_webpack_require__("worker_threads");
    var myWorker = new Worker();
}
```

This is a hidden feature of Webpack (possibly because it isn't used very often) found [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific-) that ignores `require` calls so they can be evaluated when the app is run instead of when it's bundled.

Note that this shouldn't be used for apps targeting the web browser since it will result in `resolve` being used, and web browsers don't know what `resolve` is. Only use it in code that targets Node.

Comment: Dude, holy shit, this is an awesome find deep in the docs. Thanks! I'll accept the next time I need one to make sure it works.